# ipython: prompt adding line. How to remove

Tags: ipython

After https://gist.github.com/takluyver/85b33db0836cdcc4baf252fd81937fa7

I have added  `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/01-setprompt.py`

```
    from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
    
    class Prompt(Prompts):
        def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
            return [ ( Token.Prompt, ">>> ",), ]
    
        def out_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
            return []
    
    ip = get_ipython()
    ip.prompts = Prompt(ip)
```

This adds a blank line after the output so that I get this:

```
>>> n=0

>>> n
0
```

How do I remove that blank so that I get this;

```
 >>> n=0
 >>> n
 >>> 0
```